# Change Object type to String

Tags: java

We have an assignment about ADT, Generics and Interfaces. I am stuck at the designing a method named toString(). Basically we have to change Object type to String. Interface and implementation classes like this.

```
public interface Stack<T> {
    public boolean add(T newItem);
    public boolean isEmpty();
    public boolean isFull();
}

class Stack1 implements Stack {
    public boolean add(Object newItem) { //Code }
    public boolean isEmpty() { //Code }
    public boolean isFull(); { //Code }
}

public class Items {
    @Override
    public String toString() { } //This method.
}
```

Lets assume I have an variable typed Object (or T). How can I code the toString method or How can I change a variable type.

Comment: your `Item` Object not have any attribute, so why you need a toString in this?

Comment: Firstly, don't forget to @Override your `toString()` method.  Secondly, you don't "change Object type to String", you generate a string that contains an informative representation of the state of your object.

Comment: Not only that, but `toString` is a method of the `Object` class. Given that every class is essentially an extension of the base `Object` class, you only have to override the `toString` method and provide an implementation. Normal case for doing so would be to pretty print your object's fields and values.

Comment: Yeah I know, sorry about that. Now I did not use an attribute in my code. Thats why I did not include.

Comment: Ok I will use the @Override and I still don't understand how to implement it. Sorry about that I am beginner.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me: what is your toString method supposed to DO? As said: any object in java inherits a toString already, so what is the *intend* of overwriting that method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you put `Stack`, `Stack1`, and `Items` in each separate java file with the same name (`Stack.java`, `Stack1.java`, `Items.java`, respectively). After that, you should return certain values for implementation function in `Stack1` class. For example:

```
class Stack1 implements Stack {
    public boolean add(Object newItem) {
        return true;
    }
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return true;
    }
    public boolean isFull() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Additionally, make sure your `Items`'s `toString` function always return a string. For example:

```
public class Items {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Some string";
    }
}
```

If there are no errors reported, when you run this `main` method:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Items items = new Items();
        System.out.println(items.toString());
    }
}
```

It should print out:

```
Some string
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, given that you've created the interface `Stack` with a type parameter like `T` you could simply change your `Stack1` implementation to something like:

```
class Stack1 implements Stack<String> {
    public boolean add(String newItem) { //Code }
    public boolean isEmpty() { //Code }
    public boolean isFull(); { //Code }
}
```

Or if you want to use only `Items` for this stack use:

```
class Stack1 implements Stack<Items> {
    public boolean add(Items newItem) { //Code }
    public boolean isEmpty() { //Code }
    public boolean isFull(); { //Code }
}
```

If you can't change the code for some reasons, and just update the mthods, then you can use `instanceof` to verify if the object is an instance of `String` of `Items` before use `toString()` method. Something like this:

```
public boolean add(Object newItem) {
    if (newItem instanceof String) {
        String newItemString = (String) newItem;
        System.out.println(newItemString);
    } else {
        // do something else...
    }
}
```

This will work for the `T` parameter too. Just a note, each Java class extends by default the `Object` class and the method `toString()` belong to `Object`. So you can call this methods in any Java object you want. So if you do this: `newItem.toString()` it won't fail for any object passed as parameter to the method ok?

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. But the annoying part is we can't change the classes or methods. We have to use all the methods that included in the Homework paper. So I have to implement a code that changes the type of an variable to String.

Comment: Was it answered?

Comment: Thanks again. I sent a mail to my teacher about the method. I think it is not the answer but thanks for the idea. I found it really useful.